# Spring NativeQuery and default EntityBased results

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, nativequery

I need to read database and perform mathematical calculations that will vary on the basis of different parameters using different aggregate functions.

**Explanation:**
I need to do the multiple calculations after identifying departments, there are three checks to identify departments and each of these checks further have three more conditions to check(means there are total 9 checks). Each of the condition have different bonus calculation mechanism with respect to department after identifying the seniority level extracting min and max values, these seniority levels are identified by some configuration data using another join.

To achieve this I wrote Native query using following syntax

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("Query");
```

Did I do the right thing? or should I use default repository functions and try to do the calculation with in application(although I have no idea how to do it but want to know the best approach)?

Which approach has less processing time?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: @JonathanJohx mysql

Comment: I think you should use mysql triggers on your database so that mathematical fields will be updated.

Comment: @JonathanJohx unfortunatly can't do that, requirement is to process it on an event.

Comment: I mean you execute mysql triggers manually on sql script @Just_another_developer